# Merge two accounts on iTunes?

Tags: itunes, accounts

I just noticed that I have 2 different accounts on my computers. Is it possible to ask Apple to merge them and been able to share the music I bought on each account ?

Comment: I have a similar problem but in another "domain". I have apps on my iPhone that were bought on a second account, which is also inconvient when checking for app updates. I googled a lot on the issue and have not found a solution that would allow to merge 2 accounts. Annoying, I know.

Comment: Duplicate of [Possible to merge or consolidate two iTunes Store accounts from the same household, to share apps and other purchases?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/possible-to-merge-or-consolidate-two-itunes-store-accounts-from-the-same-househol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no provision to re-sign the files that have been downloaded so by policy and by design, purchased items remain under the Apple ID used to purchase the item.

This means you can't divide up purchases after the fact (but you can agree to share the password and share the 5 authorized computers) even if you split up with a partner who shared an account with you.

You also can't "combine" past purchases - that account and password need to stay around and you can register a new "email" for communications of password resets but that original apple ID remains even long after you've left AOL or whatever name you originally used to purchase items.

Answer (score 3):

Two days ago I received an email from apple support. The author told me

> Leider muss ich Ihnen mitteilen, dass es nicht möglich ist, iTunes Accounts miteinander zu verbinden.

which means

> Unfortunately I have to tell you that it is not possible to merge iTunes accounts.

Comment: This is true and it is huge issue if already made purchases on two iTunes accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed a bit since the accepted answer to this was written…

iCloud accounts cannot be merged, even now in 2019.

What you could do is set up [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/HT201060)  & invite your old account to the "family", that way you can have legitimate access to purchases made on both accounts.